# Cannot convert from Flux<PortCall> to Mono<? extends Object>

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, reactive-mongo-java

```
public Flux<PortCall> updateByFindById(String gsisKey, PortCall portCall) {
    return portCallRepository.findAllByVesselCode(portCall.getVesselCode())
            .collectList().flatMap(list->{
                return portCallRepository.saveAll(Flux.fromIterable(list));
            });
                    
}
```

Here I'm trying to invoke saveAll() of SimpleReactiveMongoRepository i.e public  Flux saveAll(Iterable entities)

Comment: `Flux.fromIterable(list)` returns a `Flux` while `saveAll` takes a `Iterable<S>`. A `Flux` is not a `Iterable`. Try just calling `portCallRepository.saveAll(list)`. Or just skip the `collectList` and use `save` it will still just make a single transaction to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want:

```
public Flux<PortCall> updateByFindById(String gsisKey, PortCall portCall) {
    return portCallRepository.saveAll(
         portCallRepository.findAllByVesselCode(portCall.getVesselCode())
    );
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to update the list and then save into DB, the update logic has been removed to keep the question concise.